# What does this mean? *** "Delete" argument ":destroy," needs to be a number (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run the following tests for destroying a model object.

Here is one of the tests:

```
  it 'admin destroy' do
    login_as(admin)
    assert_difference('Topic.count', -1) do
      debugger;
      delete :destroy, id: topic.id
    end
    must_redirect_to forums_path
  end
```

This test fails to destroy a Topic model object. Placing a debugger; in the cod produces this;

[image]

What is this `'Delete argument destroy needs to be a number?'`

My forums destroy test works perfectly. I don't understand what the problem is. Does anyone know what this means. I placed the exact error on Google but it leads to a bunch of links with destroy argument error problems. Help would be appreciated, Thanks.

---------EDIT---------

*At the top of my controller_test file I have let `let(:topic) { create(:topic) }` from FactoryGirl if anyone was wondering.

Comment: Try using `post :destroy, id: topic.id, :_method: :delete` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse diego.greyrobot but it didn't work unfortunately. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your test fails because your topic object is created when `topic` is first referenced, i.e inside the `assert_difference` block: the overall count does not change because the topic is both created and destroyed within the block, so the net difference is 0.

If you change the `let` to `let!` then the topic will be created earlier and your test should pass.

Your problems at the byebug console are because byebug thinks you are trying to execute byebug's `delete` command (that removes a breakpoint). You can force what you enter to be evaluated as ruby code with the `e` command.